# What is the meaning and value of $(-0.5!)$?

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

What is the meaning and value of $(-0.5!)$?
I got the value as $- \frac {\sqrt \pi}{2}$or $-0.8862269$. 
I have no idea what this means.
Much appreciate your answers.

Comment: Well, the exclamation mark is the factorial (generalized to gamma function), but I'm not too sure about that question mark :P

Comment: Please use the parentheses to better disambiguate your expression: do you mean $-(0.5!)$ or $(-0.5)!$ (I suppose the former, judging by your $-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ result)?

Comment: Is your question related to factorial (exclamation mark) in general? That is, do you know what $n!$ means? Or is your question regarding how factorials of negative values are defined?

Answer (score 5):

Usually we extend the factorial to values other than nonnegative integers by identifying it with the Gamma function. This is superficially justified by the identity $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ for nonnegative integers $n$ (though there is really more to the story than that). The Gamma function is defined as

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt$$

if $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$. Otherwise it is defined by analytic continuation of one of its functional equations, such as $z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$. In your case you want $\Gamma(1/2)$, which is in the range where the integral makes sense, and it is famously equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$ as can be seen by changing variables to convert the integral into the Gaussian integral.

Comment: I think negation should have lower precedence than factorial, so the expression should parse as $-(0.5!)$. This also will then correspond to the value the OP gets: $-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$.

Answer (score 3):

The usual definition of the factorial is coherent only for a domain of natural numbers. But it is convenient sometimes to have a function which is defined on a much larger domain (e.g., the real or complex numbers) and agrees with the factorial on the naturals. This function should be some sort of sensible extension of the factorial. We have such a function, the Gamma function, and that's what's being used.

You can read about the Gamma function on Wikipedia -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 0):

For the Gamma function we have $$\Gamma (n)=(n-1)!$$

Thus $$   (-0.5!) =\Gamma (0.5)    =$$

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{-0.5} dt  = 1.772453...$$

The  exact value of the integral is known to be $\sqrt \pi$

If we like to get $-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ as an answer, we compute $-(0.5!)$

Comment: I think negation should have lower precedence than factorial, so the expression should parse as $-(0.5!)$. This also will then correspond to the value the OP gets: $-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$.